# How to build a scrollable date picker in qml

Tags: qt, datepicker, qml, qtquick2

i am trying to build a date picker which can be scrollable. Previously i made something similar for time, and its working fine. But when i tried to create a date picker with some snippets i found on web, i couldn't make it work. Here is the code i was expecting to work but when i go to that page which includes the object, my application just freezes and stops working

```
import QtQuick 2.0


ListView {

id: root

function set(date) { // new Date(2019, 10 - 1, 4)
    selectedDate = new Date(date)
    positionViewAtIndex((selectedDate.getFullYear()) * 12 + selectedDate.getMonth(), ListView.Center) // index from month year
}

signal clicked(date date);  // onClicked: print('onClicked', date.toDateString())


property date selectedDate: new Date()

width: 500;  height: 500 // default size
snapMode:    ListView.SnapOneItem
orientation: Qt.Horizontal
clip:        true

model: 3000 * 12 // index == months since January of the year 0

delegate: Item {
    property int year:      Math.floor(index / 12)
    property int month:     index % 12 // 0 January
    property int firstDay:  new Date(year, month, 1).getDay() // 0 Sunday to 6 Saturday

    width: root.width;  height: root.height

    Column {
        Item { // month year header
            width: root.width;  height: root.height - grid.height

            Text { // month year
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
                       'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'][month] + ' ' + year
                font {pixelSize: 0.5 * grid.cellHeight}
            }
        }

        Grid { // 1 month calendar
            id: grid

            width: root.width;  height: 0.875 * root.height
            property real cellWidth:  width  / columns;
            property real cellHeight: height / rows // width and height of each cell in the grid.

            columns: 7 // days
            rows:    7

            Repeater {
                model: grid.columns * grid.rows // 49 cells per month

                delegate: Rectangle { // index is 0 to 48
                    property int day:  index - 7 // 0 = top left below Sunday (-7 to 41)
                    property int date: day - firstDay + 1 // 1-31

                    width: grid.cellWidth;  height: grid.cellHeight
                    border.width: 0.3 * radius
                    border.color: new Date(year, month, date).toDateString() == selectedDate.toDateString()  &&  text.text  &&  day >= 0?
                                  'black': 'transparent' // selected
                    radius: 0.02 * root.height
                    opacity: !mouseArea.pressed? 1: 0.3  //  pressed state

                    Text {
                        id: text

                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        font.pixelSize: 0.5 * parent.height
                        font.bold:      new Date(year, month, date).toDateString() == new Date().toDateString() // today
                        text: {
                            if(day < 0)                                               ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'][index] // Su-Sa
                            else if(new Date(year, month, date).getMonth() == month)  date // 1-31
                            else                                                      ''
                        }
                    }

                    MouseArea {
                        id: mouseArea

                        anchors.fill: parent
                        enabled:    text.text  &&  day >= 0

                        onClicked: {
                            selectedDate = new Date(year, month, date)
                            root.clicked(selectedDate)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

 // Component.onCompleted: set(new Date()) // today (otherwise Jan 0000)
}
```

and i am naming this qml file as DatePicker.qml
Then i call that in another page

```
    DatePicker {
        width: 0.98 * root.width;  height: 0.8 * root.width // resize

        Component.onCompleted: set(new Date()) // today
        onClicked:             print('onClicked', Qt.formatDate(date, 'M/d/yyyy'))
    }
```

when i try to open the qml page which i created a DatePicker object, application is freezing and not giving any answer. I am struggling with where am i doing it wrong

Comment: Your model is 36000, and your delegate is really complex. It shouldn't freeze, but maybe it's just slow? What are you running it on?

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't using https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-calendar-monthgrid.html ?

Comment: Agree with Stephen, except that it's now part of the QtQuick.Controls import: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-monthgrid.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ListView`, consider using `GridView` to implement the scrollable feature. This is because in a `GridView` the geometry of each delegate is known via `cellWidth` and `cellHeight` which means the delegates needn't be created to compute the content width and height. This means you can set `model` to a very large number and you should not experience any problems with the initialization.

Also, consider using the `MonthGrid` component to render the date instead of rolling your own. You can save a lot of hassle.

Here's a mock working example:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    id: page
    property double currentTime: 0
    GridView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 2000
        cellWidth: page.width
        cellHeight: page.height
        flow: GridView.FlowTopToBottom
        snapMode: GridView.SnapOneRow
        delegate: Item {
            width: page.width
            height: page.height
            ColumnLayout {
                Text {
                    text: Qt.formatDateTime(grid.year + "-" + (grid.month + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0") + "-01", "MMMM yyyy")
                }
                DayOfWeekRow {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    locale: grid.locale
                }
                MonthGrid {
                    id: grid
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    month: index % 12
                    year: 2021 + Math.floor(index / 12)
                    locale: Qt.locale("en_US")
                    delegate: Text {
                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                        opacity: model.month === grid.month ? 1 : 0.2
                        text: model.day
                        font: grid.font
                        required property var model
                        Rectangle {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            anchors.margins: -5
                            z: -2
                            radius: 5
                            border.color: "red"
                            border.width: 3
                            color: "transparent"
                            visible: currentTime === model.date.getTime()
                        }
                        MouseArea {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            onClicked: currentTime = model.date.getTime()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAH/nicrVXfa9swEH7PXyEMg4StWpKxF0MYXcrWwULXJmsfh2pfbFFZ58lyUnfkf99JTtL8sldYvwfjO313/nR3kmWWo7Hs2l6XMnroyD2Tj1Fbg6o49H8XFZa26PwQCbA/HUaQcchyMr2RG8zB2IrFWN4rYFFpDGg7kxmErO8pX42MbyUs1+EOQkcpmoLPpVIumQvZLmYYA3mH/X5/64tAqTsZ27T+NF+6973VS5BJatfLqTe263OFy3Crg38hc4b5DD+jtZhtaYUW+YQ+vkOdkutKww0utywSB4mwxPpmIdvZlMOyUaND2qLRYYyqzHRd8oPEDjN4POV2sLQUUtP4HE0m7AXpcy3oJrQRXoEw7C0LzgJ61q6M2p2SNehxi1NrpE66PZ6LeGqFsd3hOxb0g54P6g8CsiYEVhGC3pGA1ZHnQlRX8zuABypcg+J6l34C1o21poSTVIWRUFRvr7w2XqBh4rboGtkgwI2xy/i/6nwpQyZ1DI/sDRsMT7JcD9xMDwdU1ImwKaehRNOtw95T2HFdd/dOra1fuwHoXz+nJ9rg8DycLcPiQMdPPpFyoc6VTHRGB7CO4d6+HJMDTGP4gs68jBqCb/8RjLmIpK3C+qSvZ3E0GrGd0fzEBowuEH66mg71yNcpYlE18ubo1PnU7rWRZ+B3KQ3Ez1fago6Nz98YcwORFTpR0FJph9b7ri0gEyaRugjZ2cdW/hMxmkvltydiWVKi9jz3aGIwPEKFNK4BlSN4CX997X1o5W6SWiN0UdegPflCFvLeDf/OT8XPyabpFngC3t09fRwcjm+GDSZYFnBuQLx291CPFf08IT6Q/hrCj737npV7dPbXVp3VX5dA7oA=)

Comment: Hey Stephen. Even to i added QtQuick.Controls and QtQuick.Layouts i still get the error of MonthGrid is not a type. What can be the reason for it?

Comment: What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: I am using QT Open Source with 6.2 version MinGW. I added import QtQuick.Controls but it did not work

Comment: My example is based on Qt6.4.1 but it should be similar. I am using a CMake project. You can compare my https://github.com/stephenquan/qmlonline6/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt with yours